# jQuery tipsy plugin - DelayIn not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I just added jquery tipsy plug-in to my site and I cant seem to get it working properly! It fades in just fine and the html works fine, but the delay doesn't happen. Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#navi li a').tipsy({delayIn: 500, fade: true, html: true});

})
```

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? A link to the page here: [failing demo](http://www.setarecord.com/tce/)

Comment: i have the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: Here, I've got you an answer. Matt Wiz hasn't being to this site since he asked this question - so he probably won't answer your question. If you need answers to old questions like this, consider asking a new one, and linking to the old one. Things like requesting for solutions and "me too!" should really be left as a comments (although you do not have enough rep to do so, yet)

Answer (score 4):

the download package (0.1.7) is not similar to the code that is used on the demo page. I copied the code from the demo page by hand (tipsy.css, tipsy.gif and tipsy.jquery.js) and everything works fine now. if you use the package available from the juerypage you can not use the delay and offset parameters.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the Matt Wiz's website's source code, you'll notice the technique he used. The options he used for tipsy is

```
$('a.yes').tipsy({delayIn: 500, title: 'rel', fade: true, html: true});
```

And the HTML

```
<a rel="&lt;b&gt;In This Section&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
We have plenty of ways you can help our cause! 
Check out this page for more information about how you can help 
&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight:bold;color:#ff6600&quot;&gt;The Change Exchange&lt;/span&gt; in our endeavors." 
id="howcanihelp" href="http://setarecord.com/tce/how-can-i-help/" class="yes" 
style="background-position: 0px 0px;" original-title="">
<span>How Can I Help?</span><span class="hover" style="top: 53px;"></span></a>
```

It's ugly as sin, terribly unpleasant to read (note: the original code did not have all these line spacing) and on top of all that, its horribly invalid HTML. Just **don't do this**. There are other jQuery tooltip plugins that allow you to do this without having to stick all your HTML data into an attribute, alright?